# How to create default widgets of a given type if some properties access the context?

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets say I have a `CustomMessage` class with following properties

```
class CustomMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  final Color backgroundColor;
}
```

What I want is create some default messages that will be used along in the application, such as *primary* message and *secondary* message. I would like to call those message like `CustomMessage.primary()` or `CustomMessage.secondary()`.

The idea is that `CustomMessage.primary()` use `Theme.of(context).primaryColor` and `CustomMessage.secondary()` use `Theme.of(context).accentColor`, **BUT** I cannot create a constructor like following...

```
const CustomMessage.primary(
  message = 'This is a primary text!', //this default value has no problems
  backgroundColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor, //this default value HAVE problems
)

const CustomMessage.secondary(
  message = 'This is a secondary text!', //this default value has no problems
  backgroundColor = Theme.of(context).accentColor, //this default value HAVE problems
)
```

... but I can not because `Theme.of(context).primaryColor` is not a constant value.

Can I create this default widgets if is necessary to access the context? If not, how can I accomplish something similar?

Comment: Remove the `const` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

**OutPut**

[image]

Create `ModelWidget` like

```
class CustomMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;

  late final int index;

  CustomMessage.primary(this.message) {
    index = 1;
  }

  CustomMessage.secondary(this.message) {
    index = 2;
  }
  CustomMessage.pink(
    this.message,
  ) {
    index = 4;
  }
  CustomMessage.primaryDark(
    this.message,
  ) {
    index = 3;
  }

  getColor(BuildContext context) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        return Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
      case 2:
        return Theme.of(context).accentColor;
      case 3:
        return Colors.pinkAccent;

      case 4:
        return Colors.pink;

      default:
        return Colors.green;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Center(child: Text(message)),
        color: getColor(context));
  }
}
```

and use like this

```
children: [
            CustomMessage.primary(
          "primaryWidget",
        ),
        CustomMessage.secondary(
          "accentColor widget",
        ),
          ],
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My bad explaining the problem. I edited the explaination. The thing is that I need CustomMessage.secondary to use Theme.of(context).accentColor as the backgroundColor.

Comment: What if I need CustomMessage.primaryDark() with Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark or a fourth one. I think this is not scalable.

Comment: either we can convert bool to int and or pass color value, do you get it?

Comment: check updated answer, hope it will satisfy you now.